# why firebase is not sending email confirmation to new user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm just making a simple single-page app with react js and firebase. in the authentication, part users can create a new account with email and password but to login first they need to verify their email.

My code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authuser) => {
      if (authuser){
        setuser(authuser);
      }
      else{
        setuser(null);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    }

  },[user,username]);

  const signup = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var user = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .then((authuser) => {
      authuser.user.updateProfile({
        displayName : username
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );

    user.then((authuser) => {
        authuser.user.sendEmailVerification(); 
    })
    .then(() => {alert("We have send you an confirmation email to verify your account")})
    .catch((error) => { return; })
    .then(() => {handleClose()});
  }

  const signin = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    auth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .then(() => {loghandleClose()})
    .catch((error) => {alert(error.message)})
  }
```

After creating new user signup method skipping the send confirmation email part why and user get automatically login when they create new account.
I think **onAuthStateChanged()** function run automatically when new user created and skip the send confirmation email part of signup method.

how I can fix it please.

Answer (score 0):

i solve it by myself this how I changed my code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((authuser) => {
      if (authuser && authuser.emailVerified === true){
        setuser(authuser);
      }
      else{
        auth.signOut();
        setuser(null);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    }

  },[user,username]);

  const signup = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    )
    .then((authuser) => {
      authuser.user.updateProfile({
        displayName : username
      })
      authuser.user.sendEmailVerification(); 
    })
    .then(() => {alert("We have send you an confirmation email to verify your account")})
    .catch((error) => { alert(error.message) })
    .then(() => {handleClose()});
  }

  const signin = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    auth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
    .catch((error) => {alert(error.message)})
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user.user.emailVerified){
        auth.signOut();
        alert("Please verify your email first");
      }
    })
    .then(() => {loghandleClose()})
  }
```